# Training py_faster_rcnn on VOC dataset with one class

Tags: python, deep-learning, pycaffe

I am using py_faster_rcnn to train the system for one class ('person'). Originally, it gave me an assertion error similar to this post
[How to train new fast-rcnn imageset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31005463/how-to-train-new-fast-rcnn-imageset)

So I made the following changes to my imdb.py file:

```
for b in range(len(boxes)):
    if boxes[b][2] < boxes[b][0]:
       boxes[b][0] = 0
assert (boxes[:,2] >= boxes[:,0]).all()
```

After the above changes, I get this new error. Has anyone come across this error or what may I be doing wrong?

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "./tools/train_faster_rcnn_alt_opt.py", line 130, in train_rpn
max_iters=max_iters)
File "/home/microway/test/pytest/py-faster-rcnn/tools/../lib/fast_rcnn/train.py", line 134, in train_net
pretrained_model=pretrained_model)
File "/home/microway/test/pytest/py-faster-rcnn/tools/../lib/fast_rcnn/train.py", line 53, in __init__
self.solver.net.layers[0].set_roidb(roidb)
File "/home/microway/test/pytest/py-faster-rcnn/tools/../lib/roi_data_layer/layer.py", line 68, in set_roidb
self._shuffle_roidb_inds()
File "/home/microway/test/pytest/py-faster-rcnn/tools/../lib/roi_data_layer/layer.py", line 26, in _shuffle_roidb_inds
widths = np.array([r['width'] for r in self._roidb])
KeyError: 'width'
```

Comment: It looks the members of _roibd has no attribute "width"...

Comment: will this be an issue with my annotation files? they all contain the parameter "width"